# Вопрос по :hover, :active и т.п.

Tags: jquery, hover, html, javascript, css

В общем, имеем блок.
К нему подключен стиль :active и прозрачность.
Смысл в том, чтобы при нажатии на блок он становился прозрачным.
Однако, когда отводишь мышку, то он снова становится не прозрачным, а это уже ни к чему. Нужно чтобы после нажатия он всегда оставался прозрачным.
Как такое сделать?
Подозреваю, что без JavaScript такое сделать невозможно?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно сделаь через label,

вариант 1  - переключатель с возвратом:

html:

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <div></div>
</label>
```

css:

```
.switch div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 140px;
    width: 220px;
}
.switch input:checked + div {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.switch input {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sa81jgvm/2/

вариант 2 - переключатель в одну сторону

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch"/>
<div><label for="switch"></label></div>
```

css:

```
#switch + div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 140px;
    width: 220px;
}
#switch + div label {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#switch:checked +  div {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#switch:checked + div {
    pointer-events: none;
}
#switch {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sa81jgvm/3/

Comment: КРУТЯК!!! Большое спасибо! Это именно то, что нужно было!!!

Comment: я там немного тормознул, чтобы получить эфект второго варианта, в первом надо всего лишь radio сделать вместо чекбокса.

Comment: Точно! Уже проверил!
Большое Вам спасибо! Всё работает на УРА! :)

Comment: @Mimino, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Тут не обойтись лишь стилями, ты прав. 
Вот набросок того, что тебе нужно, если я правильно понял:
http://jsfiddle.net/sa81jgvm/1/

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых случаях удобней по селектору #target